# Tpl implementation issue

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, async-await, task-parallel-library, webclient

[Tpl Sample Click here to download](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5Qm7zuWdweWZE5GNmQ1U0dTXzg)

Hi ,
I am trying to implement tpl in my project . where i have created 5 parallel HTTP call using web client .

**What i am trying to achieve.**
If any of 5 parallel call return me string containing "First" Then kill rest call and continue with call returned "First" .

**What i have tried :**

I have attached sample code above. where i have used following Predicate function.

```
async Task<T> WhenAny<T>(IEnumerable<Task<T>> tasks, Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        var taskList = tasks.ToList();
        Task<T> completedTask = null;
        do
        {
            completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(taskList);
            taskList.Remove(completedTask);
        } while (!predicate(await completedTask) && taskList.Any());

        return completedTask == null ? default(T) : await completedTask;
    }
```

And calling this as below:

```
 public async Task<string> methodname()
    {
        string sUrl = "https://abcd.com/test.php";
        Task<string> task1 = DownLoadData(sUrl);
        Task<string> task2 = DownLoadData(sUrl);
        Task<string> task3 = DownLoadData(sUrl);
        Task<string> task4 = DownLoadData(sUrl);
        Task<string> task5 = DownLoadData(sUrl); 
        var tasks = new[] { task1, task2, task3, task4, task5 };
        await WhenAny(tasks, t => t.Contains("First"));

        return "";


    }
```

But it don't met criteria. Please suggest where i am missing something. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why did you reinvent Task.WhenAny ? And what do you mean "kill rest"? You can't tell the *HTTP server* to stop processing, unless the server itself provides such an API

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos They didn't.

Comment: @Servy I see that now. Unfortunate method name in this case

Comment: i need to check task.any returned particular string or not. As i mentioned If any task returned "First" Then i need to remove rest and continue with task returned "First".

If there are any alternate solution please suggest.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos  By word killing i mean just to remove rest task from list and return only relevant task result.

Comment: You need to use cancellation token here, and slightly rewrite your code

Comment: @VMAtm I think cancelation token is used for cancel task. from above example i am able to remove task which not met condition i provided. i just want to understand what will happen when following line will execute:

await WhenAny(tasks, t => t.Contains("First"));

Comment: You need token to cancel all other tasks after you got the first one. And you do need to read more documentation on this. Your code is very poorly written

Comment: @VMAtm I am really new in tpl. i am asked to do it urgently. i have attached source code above in question. if possible can u please look into my code and suggest where i can correct it.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you have a list of urls to check rather than checking the same url repeatedly(?!) but the same method can be used in any event....

I like to use [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) for this sort of thing. It lets you chain together multiple async operations (e.g. downloading the string) with multiple sync operations (like checking the content for the substring "First") and provides all manner of 'knobs' to tweak controlling degrees of parallelism, buffer size, etc. We can also pass a cancelation token to cancel further processing. So first let's create a cancellation token source:

```
var cancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
```

Now, our first 'block' would be a `TransformBlock<string,string>`. It's this block's job to take the url string and 'transform' it into a content string by calling your `DownloadData` function:

```
var downloadBlock = new TransformBlock<string,string>(
        async s => await DownloadData(s), 
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10, //allow up to 10 simulteneous downloads
            BoundedCapacity = 100,       //allow the block to store up to 100 urls in a buffer
            CancellationToken = cancellationSource.Token 
        });
```

The second block would be a `TransformMany<string,string>` block. This type of block allows us to transform a string into a collection of strings. We just give this the job of filtering out any content strings which dont meet our criteria by returning an empty collection:

```
    var filterBlock = new TransformManyBlock<string,string>(
        s => {
                if (s.Contains("First")) 
                {
                    return new string[]{s};
                } else 
                {
                    return new string[]{};
                }
            }); // (we could also pass a cancellation token here)
```

The last block is where you would do something with the content string you have found (i.e. the first downloaded content you found that contains "First"). We also `Cancel()` our cancellation token source to prevent us starting processing of any new urls once we have found one meeting our criteria:

```
var finalBlock = new ActionBlock<string>(
        s => {
                cancellationSource.Cancel();
                //do whatever you want with the content string here            
            });
```

All that we need to do now is join up the blocks and feed in the URLs:

```
downloadBlock.LinkTo(
    filterBlock,
    new DataflowLinkOptions
    {
        PropagateCompletion = true // this flag ensures that if the first block completes ALL urls it signals to the nect block that no more will come
    }
);
filterBlock.LinkTo(
    finalBlock,
    new DataflowLinkOptions
    {
        PropagateCompletion = true,
        MaxMessages = 1         //we are only interested in the first message that arrives in our final block
    });

downloadBlock.Post("http://url.com/blah1");
downloadBlock.Post("http://url.com/blah2");
// etc...

downloadBlock.Complete(); // this signals that we've ran out of Urls to process
finalBlock.Completion.Wait(); //now wait for any messages we have 'in progress' to work through the pipeline
```

Comment: Thanks Stewart_R i will make a try with this solution and update you soon. after that i will mark this as answer.